Understanding and Validating PLS Regression Coefficients
In this problem, the goal is to understand and validate the coefficients of a Partial Least Squares (PLS) regression model. The PLS regression equation is assumed to be in the form of  y = b + b_1(X_1) + b_n(X_n)..., where  y  is the dependent variable, b  is the intercept, b_1  to  b_n  are the coefficients, and  X_1 to  X_n  are the independent variables.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


# Filtrar por municipios
municipios = ['Irapuato', 'Celaya', 'Salamanca']
data = df[df['municipio'].isin(municipios)]

columnas = ['t confirmados', 'imeca (pm2.5)', 'imeca so2', 'imeca co', 'imeca no2', 'imeca (pm 10)' ,'imeca o3']
data = data[columnas]

# Convertir a valores de numpy después de la selección y filtrado
data_values = data.values

# Variable dependiente y variables independientes
y = data_values[:, 0]  # 't confirmados'
X = data_values[:, 1:]  # 'imeca (pm2.5)', 'imeca so2', 'imeca co', 'imeca no2', 'imeca (pm 10)', 'imeca o3'

# Número de componentes para PLS
n_components = 6

# Almacenar RMSEP para cada componente
rmsep = []
best_model = None
best_rmsep = np.inf

for i in range(n_components):
    pls = PLSRegression(n_components=i+1)
    residuals = []
    
    # Validación cruzada dejando uno fuera
    for j in range(len(y)):
        X_train = np.delete(X, j, axis=0)
        y_train = np.delete(y, j, axis=0)
        X_test = X[j].reshape(1, -1)
        y_test = y[j]
        
        pls.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = pls.predict(X_test)
        
        residuals.append((y_pred - y_test)**2)
    
    # Calcular RMSEP
    rmsep_i = np.sqrt(np.mean(residuals))
    rmsep.append(rmsep_i)
    
    # Guardar el modelo con el RMSEP más pequeño
    if rmsep_i < best_rmsep:
        best_rmsep = rmsep_i
        best_model = pls

# Entrenar el mejor modelo con todos los datos
best_model.fit(X, y)
# Imprimir las predicciones
for i, pred in enumerate(y_pred):
    print(f'Datos de prueba {i+1}: t confirmados predichos = {pred[0]}')
print(best_model.coef_)

The issue arises when attempting to print the coefficients using print(best_model.coef_). While this command does return coefficients, using them in the regression equation doesn't yield correct results. However, using best_model.predict(new_data) for prediction does provide accurate results.
The approach of manually setting X values one by one and calculating the model seems to give correct coefficients that align with predictions made using best_model.predict(new_data).
The problem likely lies in how the coefficients are being printed and accessed. The goal is to understand why printing the coefficients directly doesn't work as expected and find a reliable method to extract and use them in the regression equation.
I hope to know the method for obtaining the coefficients of the PLS regression.
